# ¿Cómo crear una clase cual simula la BBDD en ASP.NET MVC usando el enfoque Code First?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con ASP.NET MVC usando Visual Studio 2017 aplicando el enfoque Code First. Tengo tres clases (tablas) en modelo y estoy intentando crear una clase cual simula la BBDD.

```
 public class DataBase
{
    private static List<Proveedor> proveedors= new ArrayList();
    private static List<Factura> facturas= new ArrayList();
    private static List<FacturadeArticulo> facturadeArticulos= new ArrayList();

    public static getProveedor()
    {
        return proveedors;
    }
    public static getFactura()
    {
        return facturas;
    }
    public static getFacturadeArticulo()
    {
        return facturadeArticulos;
    }
}
```

Necesito hacer esto y guardar datos en memoria sin usar base de datos.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para implementar lo que planteas, primero no se usa `static` y segundo deberias usar interfaces y si puedes inyeccion de dependencia, esto es una tecnica muy usada cuando quieres crar `mock` para testear el codigo

```
interface IDataBase
{
    List<Proveedor> getProveedor();
    List<Factura> getFactura();
    List<FacturadeArticulo> getFacturadeArticulo();
}

public class DataBase : IDataBase
{
    private List<Proveedor> proveedors;
    private List<Factura> facturas;
    private List<FacturadeArticulo> facturadeArticulos;

    public  DataBase()
    {
        this.proveedors= new List<Proveedor>();
        this.facturas= new List<Factura>();
        this.facturadeArticulos= new List<FacturadeArticulo>();
    }

    public List<Proveedor> getProveedor()
    {
        //aqui accedes a la db
        return proveedors;
    }

    public List<Factura> getFactura()
    {
        //aqui accedes a la db
        return facturas;
    }

    public List<FacturadeArticulo> getFacturadeArticulo()
    {
        //aqui accedes a la db
        return facturadeArticulos;
    }
}

public class DataBaseMock : IDataBase
{
    private List<Proveedor> proveedors;
    private List<Factura> facturas;
    private List<FacturadeArticulo> facturadeArticulos;

    public  DataBase()
    {
        this.proveedors= new List<Proveedor>();
        this.facturas= new List<Factura>();
        this.facturadeArticulos= new List<FacturadeArticulo>();
    }

    public List<Proveedor> getProveedor()
    {
        return proveedors;
    }

    public List<Factura> getFactura()
    {
        return facturas;
    }

    public List<FacturadeArticulo> getFacturadeArticulo()
    {
        return facturadeArticulos;
    }
}
```

la idea es que puedas cambiar la implementacion sin afectar el resto del codigo, es aqui donde se usan framework como ser Unity, Ninject, autofact, etc para inyectar la clase concreta segun quieras trabjar con mock o con la implementacion real

En el codigo se supone que uses la interfaz

```
public class xxController {

   private IDataBase database;

   public xxController(IDataBase database){
      this.database = database;
   }

   public void xxAction(...){
      var result = database.getProveedor();
      //resto codigo
   }

}
```

algunos ejemplos de lo que intento explicar

[Inserción de dependencias de ASP.NET MVC 4](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection)

[Dependency Injection In ASP.NET MVC 5](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Lo que estoy intentando es guardar datos en memoria, borar y buscar. Para crear el item uso lo siguiente codigos en la classe  DataBase

Comment: public Proveedor Add(Proveedor item)  
        {  
            if (item == null)  
            {  
                throw new ArgumentNullException("item");  
            }  
            proveedors.Add(item);  
            return item;  
        }

Comment: ok pero que sea en memoria o no, no tiene nada que ver con la forma en que implementas el servicio, si usas IoC (Inverison of Control) puedes inyectar una instancia que use memoria u otra que se conecte a la db, puediendo cambiar de una a otra

Comment: Lo necesito que sea en memoria

Comment: entonces realiza la implementaicon que mantenga los datos en memoria, en la libreria de IoC solo debes definirlo que sea singleto, leiste algo relacionado con Dependency Injection que comente ?

Comment: He leido los documentos que comentaste pero estoy confudido con IoC. Gracis por ayuda

Comment: Parte inferior de la pregunta mostré el procedimiento que estaba haciendo.

Comment: a que te refieres cuando dices "No se porque no puede anadir el nuevo item" ? recuerda que la instancia de IDatabase que seguro tienes en el constructor del controller debe ser inyectada por alguna libreria como ser Unity, Ninject, etc

Comment: recuerda ademas editar la pregunta no agregar respuestas si quieres ampliarla

Comment: la instancia de IDatabase que  en el constructor del controller esta inyectada por  libreria Unity pero sin resultado

Comment: entonces tienes que revisar como implementas Unity, si es que este no esta inyectando la instancia de la clase en el constructor

Comment: En UnityConfig tengo el codigo container.RegisterType<IDataBase, DataBase>(); y en global.asax : UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();

Comment: pareciera estar correcto, si pones un breakpoint en el global.asax pasa la ejecucion por alli? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Dependency-Injection-in-11d54863

Comment: La ejecucion en el global.asax pasa sin ningun problema..

Comment: entonces no entiendo, Unity deberia resolver he inyectar o dar un error, quizas debas abrir otra pregunta planteado la situacion porque diferente al planteo que realizas en esta

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estoy intentando es crear nuevo item en la tabla Proveedor..Tengo problema con insertar o crear un nuevo item..en la clase DataBase

```
public class DataBase : IDataBase
```

{
    private List proveedors;
    private List facturas;
    private List facturadeArticulos;

```
public  DataBase()
{
    this.proveedors= new List<Proveedor>();
    this.facturas= new List<Factura>();
    this.facturadeArticulos= new List<FacturadeArticulo>();
}
public Proveedor AddProveedor(Proveedor item)
{
    // acces db
        if (item == null)  
        {  
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");  
        }  

        proveedors.Add(item);  
        return item; 

}
```

}

En interface:

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    Proveedor Add(Proveedor item);

}
```

No se porque no puede anadir el nuevo item..
En controllador tengo los codigos:

```
public ActionResult Create(Proveedor proveed)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            var data = database.Add(proveed);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Con este codigo no tengo ningun error..